# Create VCF file from SharePoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I have a SharePoint contacts list, I did write the code to get the item and everything but I can't figure out a way to convert the item into vcf file format.
I am using Client side object model and don't want to use webservice to get the item as xml and then convert to vcf.

Can anyone have a clue for this requirement?

Comment: VCF isn't a standard return format of SharePoint data, so you either are going to have to get it as XML or JSON via a SOAP/REST endpoint and convert that to VCF or from your CSOM calls to get the data in that format.

Comment: Can you help me get data in XML then?